# Convert an array of integers into an array of strings in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array:

```
int_array = [11, 12, 14]
```

I need to convert it into

```
str_array = ['11','12','14']
```

Can you let me know how to get output link above in JQuery....

When i do looping giving error as,

```
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a
...ype&&b?!0:"array"===c||0===b||"number"==typeof b&&b>0&&b-1 in a}var t=function(a...
```

Comment: Why?  Variables in Javascript can be anything you want, at the time of using them.  Tell us the reason and there will probably be a better answer.

Comment: I can't loop int_array one by one and get output???

Comment: Yes you can.  Tell us how you want to use the array.  You probably don't need to do this at all.

Comment: You just have a syntax error.  Converting to a string will not fix that error and has nothing to do with it.  I suggest closing this question and asking the correct one (what is wrong with my loop?)

Comment: but when i do looping for this array  ['11','12','14'] i am getting output

Comment: Look at this basic example.  You're asking the wrong question.... http://jsfiddle.net/x42rxLqw/

Answer (score 3):

Try to pass the `type` into the `map` function,

```
var str_array = int_array.map(String);
```

For older versions of browsers,

```
var str_array = [];

for(var i=0;i<int_array.length;i++) {
   str_array[str_array.length] = int_array[i] + ""; 
}
```

Comment: TypeError: events.map is not a function
str_array = events.map(String);

Comment: @RubyOnRails What is the browser that you are using right now?

Comment: I am using firefox browser

Comment: for Chrome browser getting error as Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '17' in [10, 33, 34, 7, 8]

Comment: Is it problem with my jquery file or what?

Answer (score 1):

Another way, without Jquery:

```
var arrayString = int_array.join();
var str_array =  arrayString.split(",");
```

Comment: `int_array.join(",");` You don't need to pass "," explicitly. It is the default one.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I didn't know this fact, until now. I updated my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want, but Javascript will convert the types when needed automatically, be aware of that.

```
int_array.map(function(elem) {
    return String(elem)
});
```

NORMAL VERSION (OLD THINGS > : (  )

```
for (var i in int_array) { 
    int_array[i] = String(int_array[i]) 
}
```

Could you please explain in more detail why you need it? (just curious)

Comment: Giving error TypeError: events.map is not a function. Their is space after integer

Comment: try the normal version @RubyOnRails

Comment: If i loop my array $.each(events, function(index, item) {
        alert(item);
    }); not happening

Answer (score 0):

Updated.

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ifch0o1/q9gwr522/6/)

```
int_array = [11, 12, 14];
str_array = [];
$.each(int_array, function(index, value) {
  str_array.push(Number(value).toString());
});
```